# putText does not work in opencv3.0

Tags: java, opencv3.0

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class Testingopencv 
{

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      System.loadLibrary("opencv_java300");

      Mat src = Imgcodecs.imread("m.jpg");
      Mat temp = new Mat(src.rows(),src.cols(), src.type());

      Imgproc.putText(src, "Edited by me", new Point(src.rows()/2,src.cols()/2),
            Core.FONT_ITALIC, 1.0 ,new  Scalar(255));
      Imgcodecs.imwrite("watermarked.jpg", src);
   }
}
```

I am trying to use OpenCV 3.0 to make a watermark on a image but there is a problem with `putText`, I have searched around the internet but there is no solution.

The error message is:

> The method putText(org.opencv.core.Mat, java.lang.String, org.opencv.core.Point, int, double, org.opencv.core.Scalar) in the type Imgproc is not applicable for the arguments (org.opencv.core.Mat, java.lang.String, java.awt.Point, int, double, org.opencv.core.Scalar)

And the parameters should be correct as the message shown above.
How can I solve this?

Comment: You must give more information on the error you receive, or the expected and actual output of your program.

Comment: You're using `java.awt.Point` instead of `org.opencv.core.Point`

Answer (score 2):

The error message already shows the issue:

> The method putText(org.opencv.core.Mat, java.lang.String, **org.opencv.core.Point**, int, double, org.opencv.core.Scalar) in the type Imgproc is not applicable for the arguments (org.opencv.core.Mat, java.lang.String, **java.awt.Point**, int, double, org.opencv.core.Scalar)

Be sure to pass to `putText` the point as `org.opencv.core.Point` instead of `java.awt.Point`.

Answer (score 2):

This code is working.

```
// Draw a bounding box around each face.
        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray())
        {
            Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 255));
            // for crop face
            rectCrop = new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);   

            Core.putText(image, "Edited by me", new Point(rect.x,rect.y),
                    Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0 ,new  Scalar(0,255,255));
        }
```